# Relationship between Regression and Correlation

Tags: regression, correlation

In a typical regression scenario, when two independent variables are collinear, this will cause standard errors of the coefficients to be inflated. What happens if there is a perfect correlation between one of your independent variables and response variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both regression and correlation implicitly assume the following linear model:
$$
y = X\beta + \varepsilon
$$

Where y is your dependent variable, the columns of X are the independent variables, $\beta$ is the vector of coefficients and $\varepsilon$ is noise.

The only way that you can have a perfect correlation is if there is no noise, i.e. $\varepsilon=0$. And since you have no noise, that also means that you can have no uncertainty about your coefficient estimates in this case, so your standard errors are all 0 (assuming X is full-rank).

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about regression with one predictor:

$$ E(Y_i | X = x_i) = \alpha + \beta x_i$$

Then the least squares regression coefficient estimate is

$$ \hat {\beta} =  \frac{ \rho \times \sigma_y }{ \sigma_x } $$

$\rho$ is the correlation between x and y, and the sigmas are the two standard deviations.

Comment: So what is your answer to the question?

Comment: I answered the question in the title Richard

Comment: Plug in 1 for $\rho$ if there's perfect correlation

Comment: The question appears to be about the standard errors of the parameter estimates.  (If it were only about the relationship between correlation and regression it would be closed as a duplicate: that discussion is well covered on this site.)